# Python regex module not finding all matches even with overlapping = True

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am using the PyPy [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with overlapping match support.

I have the following code in which I have a string A and I am looking for a DNA pattern defined in the regular expression using regex. I want to find all matches with my RE including the overlapping ones. regex is missing one of the matches and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
import regex as re
A = "GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG"
GQ_list = re.findall(r"[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}", A, overlapped=True)
```

GQ_list returns:

```
['GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG']
```

This is missing `"GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG"` which is in my string `A` and matches the regular expression pattern. What is wrong here? What changes should I make to get all matches possible including the overlapping ones?

Comment: I don't see an `overlapped` parameter in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: This is regex not the normal python re. Normal python re does not have the overlapping = True option.

Comment: Got a link to its documentation?

Comment: it was mentioned in the title but added it to the code as well.

Answer (score 4):

**tdlr**: With the possibility of multiple regex matches at the same starting string index, `re.findall` or other regex methods will only find 1 match per starting index. You have to break up the search to find them all...

---

The issue you have is that a regex findall does **not** find all combinations from every index; it finds only **one** match from each index in turn -- usually the longest match. The techniques that find overlapping matches will still miss the multiple matches possible from a single string index. You need to modify your approach.

If you inspect your regex:

```
([G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6})
```

you will note that a matched sequence must start with a minimum of 3 `G`'s and end with the same sequence. The sequence between the `GGG[in_between_part]GGG` is as short as 9 characters and as long as 84 characters (and that may contain the same starting / ending sequence of `'GGG'`'s).

We can use that information to find all possible string sequences that fit that description. Then we use your regex to filter that the identified sequence are indeed the ones we want.

First find the string index of every possible `'GGG'` which is where a sub string would start or end (by definition):

```
s = "GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG"

offset=0
indicies=[]
while (s_idx:=s[offset:].find('GGG'))>-1:
    indicies.append(s_idx+offset)
    offset+=s_idx+1

>>> indicies
[0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 47, 66]
# these are the indicies of 'GGG' that might be that start or end
# of a sub string of interest.
```

Now we have the starting index of every `'GGG'` in your string. We can now use a regex and the bisect module to filter for all possible matches in the string of your regex.

We are using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to find ending position of a candidate ending anchor, which is the same as the start anchor. The bisect module allows us to construct a slice that form sub strings that a) Start with `'GGG'` (from the `indicies` list) and b) end with `'GGG'` and c) have a length in-between the start and end anchors of between 9 and 84 characters. We then use [re.fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) to assure the candidate substring fully matches your pattern:

```
import re 
import bisect 

matches=[]  
min_len=3+9
max_len=3+84
pat=re.compile(r'([G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6})')
for x in indicies:
    min_offest=bisect.bisect(indicies,x+min_len)
    max_offset=bisect.bisect(indicies,x+max_len)
    for idx in indicies[min_offest:]+indicies[max_offset:]:
        candidate=s[x:idx+3]
        if pat.fullmatch(candidate):
            matches.append(candidate)
```

Now we can print all the matches found, with their index in `s` and length:

```
>>> for ss in matches: print((s.index(ss), len(ss)),ss)
# This is only a primitive shortcut. If you want the actual
# index, save it when 'candidate' matches the regex
```

Prints all eight unique matches, including from the same starting index:

```
(0, 50) GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG
(0, 69) GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
(1, 49) GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG
(1, 68) GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
(8, 61) GGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
(9, 60) GGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
(10, 59) GGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
(11, 58) GGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
```

---

Note:

As stated in comments, the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) **does** support variable width lookbehinds.

You could therefore be tempted to do:

```
m1=regex.findall(r'([G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6})', s, overlapped=True)     
# produces 6 unique matches 
m2=regex.findall(r'(?<=([G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}))', s, overlapped=True)
# produces 2 matches, but one is a duplicate from m1
```

While this combo finds 1 extra string, the one you were looking for, it does not find all 8 unique matches. The string `GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG` at index 1 is missed.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Improved Answer

the cause to this problem lies in the way "RegEx positive look behind" is done

Under normal circumstances, after a string is matched from pos 1:

```
patern = r"[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}"

GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
^
```

regex advances one position:

```
GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG
 ^
```

And matches from there.
This then, will not match
GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG (since it starts at the same position as the first match)

And it will not match
GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG
as it starts at the same position as the 2nd match)

using positive look behind, it is possible to also (re)match from the same starting position.
Regex:

```regex
(?<=([paterntomatch]))

//  ?<=  indicates positive look behind
```

**WARNING: Example below might produce double results (find one occurrence twice**

So... I have given it a shot in python using a recursive function which tries to rematch a match.substring(0,match.Length-1)

```
import re

def regexRecursive(patern,subject):
    master_results = []
    results = re.findall(patern, subject)
    for result in results:
        master_results.append(result)
        length = (len(result)-1)
        subresults = regexRecursive(patern,result[0:length])
        for subresult in subresults:
            master_results.append(subresult)
    return master_results

patern = r"(?=([G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}[ACTG]{1,33}[G]{3,6}))"

given = "GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG"

expected_yield = ['GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGGTCCACAGCCACGGTTTGGG',
 'GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG',
 'GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG']

results = regexRecursive(patern, given)

for result in results:
    if result not in expected_yield:
        print ("\033[91m","Found Unexpected: ",result,"\033[0m")

for expected in expected_yield:
    if expected not in results:
        print ("\033[91m","Missing Expected: ",expected,"\033[0m")
    else:
        print ("\033[92m","Found Expected: ",expected,"\033[0m")
```

which yields the full complement of 8 substrings

Comment: My code outputs 6 strings too but "GGGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG" is also missing from your code.

Comment: I am sorry I mis counted..

I also found "GGGAGAAGGGGGGCCTTCCTGGGTCCCCGAGAGTGCAGACATGCCTGGG" bringing the total of expected strings to 8

Comment: yeah that too. There might be something wrong with the package.

Comment: should a streak of 3 Gs (GGG) always break a [ACTG]{1,33} pattern? because  [ACTG]{1,33} would also be able to match GGG (not part of you initial question, but i am trying to sort a couple of things out)

Comment: Yeah there well could be a GGG or more Gs in a row in [ACTG]{1,33}.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your thorough explanation. This solution works.

Comment: What do you mean by double results in your solution?

Comment: "(?=([a]{1,3}))" in aaa should return a,a,a,aa,aa,aaa but due to recursion it returns a,a,a,a,aa,aa,aaa (one to many single a )

Comment: Yeah sometimes it has multiple of something. I fixed that with the list(set() thing. If you do that it seems to always produce the right thing though.

Comment: if you are only interested in any unique occurrence, and not how many times or where, than it is fine.

Comment: I have thousands of sequences. Is there any way to speed the algorithm up?

Comment: @KamyarYazdani: The solution I posted should be substantially faster. Have a look...

Comment: @WSiebelder: If I try your C# regex, I only get 2 matches -- same as the Python regex module. Please explain? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBT4UwDD6zX9FwggSJLyQexBcli9lFLorxgByWMXEJbxg6FEP47VjAvHi12db1@9qvWxVeKFTLMqCxDTx9o9OnlP2N4kKPLn7UzdDK/n786DWi6SymjDHVSkR4ts64VtdsYh466YyCz87UkEtjA3Q9aZUVyL7BkHmU4@0YIBzBF2SZyDKxGedFQZtu5DhfGVEITo5nhTgzFIn1pKBYIT8lVXqiHqGRTipJylZ/wQYFd35we3MMSlFNSXQ1lxnJVNMhSpL5v1gY@uHaK5dOvfOubbVyNAw4rbFeP7T3j/MdCHBLp8VpZF2r45feOP1grA786XI@F751g63B2OtXCwDTYfYjKvJ@6ZgT7TaEBEluZvOy/AA "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @dawg You are right.... I can not reproduce my own result... I'l remove it from the answer